About BMO space on smooth open bounded domain
Let $\Omega$ be any open domain in $\Bbb R^d$.
Define the $\text{BMO}(\Omega)$ space as
$$  \text{BMO}(\Omega)= \big\{u\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)\,\,:\,\, |u|_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)} <\infty \big\},
$$
with the seminorm,
$$|u|_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)}
=\sup_{B_r(x_0) \subset \Omega} \frac{1}{|B_r(x_0)|} \int_{B_r(x_0)} \Big| u(x) - \frac{1}{|B_r(x_0)|} \int_{B_r(x_0)} u(z) \,d z \Big| d x.$$
Let us consider the seminorm
$$|u|^*_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)}
=\sup_{x_0\in \Omega,\,r>0} \frac{1}{|\Omega\cap B_r(x_0)|} \int_{\Omega\cap B_r(x_0)} \Big| u(x) - \frac{1}{|\Omega\cap B_r(x_0)|} \int_{ \Omega\cap B_r(x_0)} u(z) \,d z \Big| d x.
$$
In particular,
$$ |u|^*_{\text{BMO}(\Bbb R^d)}=|u|_{\text{BMO}(\Bbb R^d)}.$$
Question:
1- Are the seminorms $|\cdot|_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)}$ and $|\cdot|^*_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)}$ equivalent when  $\Omega$ is a $d$-set? That is, is there $C>0$ such that
$$ |u|^*_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)}\leq C|u|_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)}$$
for $u\in \text{BMO}(\Omega)$?
Note that we clearly have $$  |u|_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)}\leq |u|^*_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)}$$
Recall that  $\Omega$ is a $d$-set if there is $c>0$ such that $|\Omega\cap B_r(a)|\geq cr^d$ for all $a\in \Omega$ and $r>0$. For instance an example of a d-set, is a Lipschitz domain.  $\Omega=\Bbb R^d_+=\{x\in \Bbb R^d\,\,:\,\, x_d>0\}$ is also a $d$-set.
2- Is the John Nirenberg inequality true on $(\text{BMO}(\Omega),|\cdot|_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)})$? That is, are there $a>0, b>0$ such that , for any $u\in \text{BMO}(\Omega)$, there holds
\begin{align*}
|\{x \in B : |u(x) - u_B| > t\}| &\leq a |B|
\exp\Big(\frac{-b t}{|u|_{\text{BMO}(\Omega)}}\Big).
\end{align*}
for any ball $B\subset \Omega$ and $t>0$?
Any reference or answer is welcome.
